# Angular HTTP interceptor error not refreshing view

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am following this tutorial https://angular-academy.com/angular-jwt/ and I need a little help with my HTTP interceptor class.

When I successfully refresh the token after 401 (Unauthorized error), the code retry the HTTP call and I get the OK back but the view and subscription isn't updating and I sometime get the following error:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
   at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
   at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
   at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:38)
   at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1974)
   at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
   at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
   at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
   at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
   at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)
   at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603) (editado)
```

This is my 401 handler:

```js
private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler,tokens) {
  if (!this.isRefreshing) {
    this.isRefreshing = true;
    this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
    return this.auth.refreshToken(tokens).pipe(
      switchMap((token: any) => {
        this.isRefreshing = false;
        this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.token);
        this.db.removeAll('token');
        this.db.storage.set('token',token);
        return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.token));
      })).subscribe(r => r);
  } else {
    return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
      filter(token => token != null),
      take(1),
      switchMap(jwt => {
        console.log(jwt)
        return next.handle(this.addToken(request, jwt));
      }));
  }
}
```

Comment: I've answered your question 1 or 2 hours ago but you deleted it right before hitting `post`. Please have a little more patience this time.

Answer (score 0):

So, here we go again.

That error is thrown because you aren't returning an observable in your `intercept()` method if the error is `401` (if I remember correctly from your first post).

You should not manually subscribe in the interceptor. Angular does that for you. You need to return an observable instead, using RxJS operators like `switchMap`. For side effects use the `tap` operator.

Your `handle401Error` after removing the subscription should be:

```
private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler,tokens) {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.auth.refreshToken(tokens).pipe(
        switchMap((token: any) => {
          this.isRefreshing = false;
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.token);
          this.db.removeAll('token');
          this.db.storage.set('token',token);

          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.token));
        }));
    } else {

      // I'm not sure about this part since to me it seems that in this block the 
      // subject it will always emit null value after the token expires and the
      // browser is refreshed because the data won't persist.
      // if I'm right use this here and should work: **return next.handle(request);**
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap(jwt => {
          console.log(jwt)
          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, jwt));
        }));
    }
  }
```

The `intercept` method:

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (this.authService.getJwtToken()) {
      request = this.addToken(request, this.authService.getJwtToken());
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
        // here don't forget tor return
        return this.handle401Error(request, next);
      } else {
        return throwError(error);
      }
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Remove .subscribe(r => r) call after next.handle. You need to return observable, not function call.

```
return next.handle(
    this.addToken(request, token.token)
);
```